# Implementation of IsPostBack in page load

Tags: asp.net, events, controls, postback

The more I use ASP.NET, the more `if (!IsPostBack) {}` seems pointless...

First example:

For example, I just Googled an issue, they said use this as part of the solution:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
   Page.LoadComplete += new EventHandler(Page_LoadComplete);
}
```

Which does exactly as coded, LoadComplete will only fire on the first load.  After clicking a button, or anything that triggers a postback, the LoadComplete event is left unhooked, thus skipping the event handler.  Therefore, their "fix" only works upon the first load = worthless.  I promptly commented out the `if (!Page.IsPostBack) {}` and now the event always triggers as desired.

Second example:

I am attempting to hook events to a dynamically created button (which by the way, I can't get to work [GRR!]).  I see examples showing this:

```
myEditToggleButton = new Button();
myEditToggleButton.ID = "editToggleButton"; 
//^GOTTA HAVE THIS FOR EVENTS TO WORK! (supposedly, I haven't seen it work...)
if (!IsPostBack)
{
   myEditToggleButton.Click += new EventHandler(myEditToggleButton_Click);
}
Controls.Add(myEditToggleButton);
```

Like the first example, my understanding is that the event wouldn't be hooked after the first page load, thus the button is "inert" after one click (because clicking triggered a postback).

Question:

When should you use `if (!IsPostBack) {}`?  I am guessing it has to do with mark-up created controls only.

Comment: Frankly, any code in the load event not wrapped in a !Page.IsPostBack is a red flag for me during code reviews.  It often indicates a misunderstanding of how webforms works, especially with regards to data binding.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In short, you use it everytime you need to execute something ONLY on first load.

The classic usage of `Page.IsPostBack` is data binding / control initialization.

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
   //Control Initialization
   //Databinding
}
```

Things that are persisted on `ViewState` and `ControlState` don't need to be recreated on every postback so you check for this condition in order to avoid executing unnecessary code.

Another classic usage is getting and processing `Querystring` parameters. You don't need to do that on postback.

Comment: Yes, Viewstate is definitely the main force behind using it

Answer (score 6):

When there is no need to repeat the operation other than the first time.

use it with expensive operations (such as getting data from a database or populating ListItems) that must be performed only the first time the page or control is loaded. If the page is posted to the server and then reloaded, there is no need to repeat the operation. By testing the value of IsPostBack, you can skip the expensive operation,

Comment: However, with any dynamically added controls, they vaporize.  Thus, for example, if you dynamically added a drop-down box, the items within at drop-down would have been vaporized with the drop-down box itself.

Comment: @Yerg, then you would need to add those controls before the if (!IsPostBack)

Comment: @Yerg this page should help you understand IsPostBack in regards to dynamic controls. http://forums.asp.net/t/1186195.aspx

Comment: @harpo But you still would need to hook the events, because the control you had previously hooked has gone to la-la-land due to the page reloading.  What you suggested is what I have in my example above, which does not work.

Comment: @Lucas Heneks Yes, I found that link during my Googlings of the day.  That is where I learned I MUST have an ID.  Danke anyway.

Answer (score 4):

It's for processing form data.

If you want to handle POSTed data, you only want to do so if the page actually posted data, not on first load. Hence, the IsPostBack flag.

Answer (score 3):

What can happen if you cause a postback is you can change the state of your controls, without meaning to. For example in using a gridview, if you postback during edit mode, you will no longer have access to your edit-ed fields.

Often you need to preserve the information from disapearing on a page when you hit the server, this is the point of

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your event handlers should be wired up whenever the event can be fired (irrespective of PostBack status)

Also, when adding controls dynamically, be sure to observe the asp [page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)            
{
    if (!IsPostBack) { 
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=-----; Database=-----; Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        conn.Open();
        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select Command",conn);
        conn.Close();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        ddlSearch.DataSource = dt;
        ddlSearch.DataTextField = "---";
        ddlSearch.DataValueField = "---";
        ddlSearch.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you must use IsPostBack if you want to initialize controls, otherwise they will be reverted to the default on every load. This will confuse the user as when they try to use the form their entered values will get reset to your defaults.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand what is postback,when you start your project in Visual Studio,
if you have a `if statement` which checks whether `isPostBack` is `true` or `false` in your `Page_Load` method, at this point, `isPostBack` is `false`, means it is not a `postback`, then what is postback,
now click a `button` (if you don't have a button,please add one and the button click method as well), at this point, you send a request back to the server, the server then response, this process is the so called `postback`, which is triggered by clicking the `button`,

one thing you really need to notice, the `Page_Load` method will be executed again, not only the `Button_click` method will be executed, so now, the `isPostBack` is `true`, means it is postback, yes, it really is a postback, because you clicked the button.