# How to retain Serial Port State after postback ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, serial-port

I am trying to send the data to serial port in ASP.net. After connecting to serial port Before postback data is being sent. But after postback i get exception while sending data.

```
'System.InvalidOperationException: The port is closed.'
```

I tried everything by connecting to port on pageload: ispostback, and disconnecting and connecting again. Still it shows same exception. Is there any way to retain the state of serial port..

here's my code. Please Help me Out...

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string indata;
    public SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (IsPostBack)
        {

            openPort("COM10");
            disconnect();
            connect();
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //disconnect();
        openPort("COM10");
        connect();
        check(TextBox1.Text); //Data Sending Successful but after postback even it doesnt work too.
    }

    public void connect()
    {
        try { sp.Open(); }
        catch (Exception e1) { MessageBox.Show(e1.ToString()); }
    }

    public void disconnect()
    {
        try { sp.Close(); }
        catch (Exception e1) { MessageBox.Show(e1.ToString()); }
    }

    public void openPort(string p)
    {
        sp.BaudRate = 9600;
        sp.Parity = Parity.None;
        sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        sp.DataBits = 8;
        sp.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        sp.PortName = p;
        sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
       // sp.ReadTimeout = 200;
       // sp.WriteTimeout = 200;
    }

    private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        Debug.WriteLine(" Data Received:");
        Debug.Write(" " + indata);
    }

    protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        check("" + (char)26); //Exception in sending
    }

    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        check("\r\n"); //exception in sending
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        check(TextBox1.Text); // exception in sending
    }
    void check(string ss)
    {
        //sp.Dispose();
        //openPort("COM10"); connect();
        if (sp.IsOpen)
            sp.Write(ss);
        else
        { 
            disconnect(); openPort("COM10"); connect(); 
            sp.Write(ss); 
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: I would not do serial port communication from a website, but have a separate, dedicated service that is always connected to the device. You can then let your site communicate with this service.

Comment: Hehe No dear.. actually you'r trying to help me :P

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify your code, so the port is configured on page load and the   one handler deals with resetting your port. The disconnect, connect, I see is complicating it. Here I have given an example of using the button click event.
Please note the missing brace below.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
string indata;
public SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            sp.BaudRate = 9600;
            sp.Parity = Parity.None;
            sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            sp.DataBits = 8;
            sp.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            sp.PortName = p;
            sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
           // sp.ReadTimeout = 200;
           // sp.WriteTimeout = 200;
        }
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
        sp.BaudRate = 9600;
        sp.Parity = Parity.None;
        sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        sp.DataBits = 8;
        sp.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        sp.PortName = p;
        sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
       // sp.ReadTimeout = 200;
       // sp.WriteTimeout = 200;
    }

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

if sp.IsOpen = False then
{
    try { sp.Open(); }
    catch (Exception e1) { MessageBox.Show(e1.ToString()); }
}
else
{
    try { sp.Close(); }
    catch (Exception e1) { MessageBox.Show(e1.ToString()); }
}

void check(string ss)
{
    //sp.Dispose();
    //openPort("COM10"); connect();
    if (sp.IsOpen)
    {//missing brace
        sp.Write(ss);
    }//missing brace
    else
    { 
        sp.Open(); 
        sp.Write(ss); 
    }
 }
}
```

**Edit 2:**

As I mentioned in the comments the code will only run once.

*The following examples are provided from the link below.*

> Have you tried writing some codes under the !IsPostBack code block to
>   check if the codes hits there when it postbacks? try this below for
>   testing

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Response.Write("First load");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Postback occurs");
        }
}
```

**OR**

> I will refer the code you want to run as One Time Code.  For what you
>   are attempting to achieve, following should work. Please note that
>   sessions also expire. So after about 20 minutes (default value) of
>   inactivity, if the user comes back to the site/hits refresh, the One
>   Time Code will run again. If you want something more persistent than
>   20 minutes you can try using cookies, but if user clears their cookies
>   your One Time Code with run again.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Session["firsttimeuser"] == null)
   {
     //put code here for One Time Code;
     Session["firsttimeuser"] = true;
   }
}
```

Please see this link:

There is lengthy discussion about this.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1314918.aspx/1

You should be able to create a solution from this, please advise.

**Edit 1**

Please see MSDN for Get Port Names:

> Use the GetPortNames method to query the current computer for a list
>   of valid serial port names. For example, you can use this method to
>   determine whether COM1 and COM2 are valid serial ports for the current
>   computer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.getportnames.aspx

And SerialPort.Open

```
 _serialPort.PortName = SetPortName(_serialPort.PortName)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.open.aspx

**Edit 3**

Try:

```
 if (!IsPostBack) or

if(!Page.IsPostBack)
```

Please see:

[Implementation of IsPostBack in page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620883/when-do-you-use-if-ispostback-in-asp-net)

[What is a postback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251157/what-is-a-postback)

and:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, I tried Your code.. Now it gives Exception
at 
    sp.Open();//'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
in check(String ss) method.

Comment: no i used ur code replaces the connect/disconnect, connection establishment on page load and on other button events used ur check method. now it gives exception
System.UnauthorizedAccessException.Access to the port 'COM1' is denied.

Comment: i have a method to get the port names. But currently i am assigning the port name with in the code, first it was "COM10", now the port name is reconfigured in device manager as "COM1".
I tried something else. I sent some data on page load where settings are done. It is Okay. But after postback when i send the data again it doesnt.

Comment: Receiving data is running perfect. but having problem with sending the data. See clearly the problem is when i send data on or after first page load it works perfect. But after the postback, sending data generates exception.

Comment: no.. lemme explain you the whole problem in short. 1)page loads 2)button1 clicked: (port open and send "AT") : Port opened and "AT" sent. PostBack Happened. 3) button2 clicked: (send another command)//exception because maybe after postback the port settings are not retained.